# Braintree PayPal Payment Gateway for react native

Tags: payment-gateway, react-native, paypal-sandbox, react-native-ios

I'm making a shopping app with `react native` and I want to integrate a payment gateway like PayPal for my app but I don't know how can I start with it because I can't found a proper way for implement this on react native.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented paypal using [react-native-paypal-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal-wrapper) it is perfect.

Comment: Do u have any example for this coz im getting confused that's why i. Need help

Comment: I have used the exact same code as given on npm js side its working

Comment: try that code out and let me know what confuses you

Comment: Sure let me try first then i can tell u what makes me confuse... Thnx for reply

Comment: im facing these issues first do u tried with credit card payment... and another one is this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336526/module-rnpaypalwrapper-error-apple-mach-o-linker-error-in-react-native

Comment: react-native-paypal-wrapper. Note: No longer maintained, happy to accept PR or takeover