# Module RNPaypalWrapper error Apple-Mach-O linker Error in react native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, paypal, react-native-ios

Hey guys Im making an app of react native after installing react native payola wrapper im facing this issues

1. Module RNPaypalWrapper requires main queue setup since it overrides `constantsToExport` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.
2. Apple-Mach-O linker Error

> ```
>  Ld /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shopping.app/Shopping
> ```
>
> normal x86_64
>           cd /Users/mac/Desktop/Tanveer/Tabtest/Shopping/ios
>           export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
>           export PATH="/Applications/Xcode_9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode_9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>           /Applications/Xcode_9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode_9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk
>   -L/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -L/Users/mac/Desktop/Tanveer/Tabtest/Shopping/ios/Pods/CardIO/CardIO -L/Users/mac/Desktop/Tanveer/Tabtest/Shopping/ios/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile
>   -F/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Shopping.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shopping.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Shopping.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Shopping.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shopping.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Shopping_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lCardIO -lPayPalMobile -lc++ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreLocation -framework
>   CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework MessageUI -framework
>   MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore
>   -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Shopping.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shopping.build/Shopping.app-Simulated.xcent
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTBlob.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTAnimation.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTAnimation.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTActionSheet.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTGeolocation.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTImage.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTLinking.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTNetwork.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTSettings.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTText.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTVibration.a
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTWebSocket.a
>   -lRNImagePicker -lRNPaypalWrapper -lPods-Shopping -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Shopping.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shopping.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Shopping_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shopping-bffzrhylanxuelcazupfwylbgyoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shopping.app/Shopping
>
> ```
>  ld: library not found for -lPods-Shopping
>     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see          invocation)
> ```

how can I resolve these errors......

Comment: You have not set it up correctly, do complete all process again

Comment: Thats why i told if you have any working example or github example.. U can share this also.. And did h check that credit card payment is working or not?

Answer (score 1):

these are the installation instruction for the package do every step carefully.

1. npm install --save react-native-paypal-wrapper or yarn add
   react-native-paypal-wrapper
2. react-native link react-native-paypal-wrapper
3. [clone this repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-ios-SDK#with-or-without-cocoapods) ( You do not need all the components in this repo
   you download selectives )
4. Add the PayPalMobile directory (containing several .h files and
   libPayPalMobile.a) to your Xcode project. We recommend checking
   "Copy items..." and selecting "Create groups...".
5. In your project's Build Settings (in the TARGETS section, not the
   PROJECTS section):

> ```
> add -lc++ -ObjC to Other Linker Flags
> enable Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)
> enable Link Frameworks Automatically
> ```

6. In your project's Build Phases, link your project with these
   libraries. Weak linking for iOS versions back to 6.0 is supported.

> ```
> Accelerate.framework
> AudioToolbox.framework
> AVFoundation.framework
> CoreLocation.framework
> CoreMedia.framework
> MessageUI.framework
> MobileCoreServices.framework
> SystemConfiguration.framework
> SafariServices.framework
> ```

7. Add the open source license acknowledgments from acknowledgments.md
   to your app's acknowledgments.
8. In your app's Info.plist, add the following URL schemes to
   LSApplicationQueriesSchemes:

> ```
> com.paypal.ppclient.touch.v1
> com.paypal.ppclient.touch.v2
> org-appextension-feature-password-management
> ```

**Note: These installation instructions were collected from [react-native-paypal-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal-wrapper#installation) and also as it suggested the [paypal ios sdk documentation](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-ios-SDK#if-you-dont-use-cocoapods-then) they were perfect for our projects**